# Make the character jump like flappy bird

Tags: lua

This is the piece of code I am using to make the bird jump, but it's not even close to making a jump like flappy bird.it goes up on touch, ut does not fall like gravity is pulling it. Infact, after a couple of seconds, it looks like the bird is at its initial position as well as the jump position(two birds on screen), what can I do to fix this?

```
function Play: whenTouched()
 self.touchStarted= true
 x,y = self.myAnim:getPosition()

        if self.touchStarted then
         speed = -16
         self.touchStarted = false
        end
     y  = y + speed;
     speed = speed + 2
     self.myAnim:setPosition(x,y)
 end
```

Comment: downvote? Any particular reason?

Comment: The reason is that you show no effort to solve the problem.  You can't just simply paste the code and say to fix it.  You may want to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Okay, thank you but not really sure what made you think that I was not making an effort to fix it.

Comment: You simply say "What can I do to fix this?"  You don't show anything you tried to solve the problem.  You just show the currently not working code.  Others will be more inclined to help you if they see that you have put in a substantial effort yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the equation you're looking for perhaps

http://www.school-for-champions.com/science/gravity_equations_upward_velocity.htm#.U60pj42SyDQ

Not sure how much math you have so If you need more help say so